# DropDownList's OnSelectedIndexChanged Does Not Fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I created these `DropDownList`s:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ComboBoxes" ID="UserComboBox" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserComboBoxSelected"/>
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ComboBoxes" ID="ShiftComboBox" runat="server"/>
```

I have this in the code-behind:

```
protected void UserComboBoxSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, it never fires when I select items in `UserComboBox`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `[AutoPostBack][1]` to true for firing event on server side code behind file.

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ComboBoxes" ID="UserComboBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserComboBoxSelected"/>
```

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a postback to the server
>   automatically occurs when the user changes the list selection, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    CssClass="ComboBoxes" 
    ID="UserComboBox" 
    runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserComboBoxSelected" 
    AutoPostBack="true" />
```